# Joomla 3.0 not echoing usertype

Tags: variables, joomla, joomla3.0, usertype

I made the following code to get some user variables in a flash app:

```
<?php
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
echo $user->get('username') ;
echo $user->get('id') ;
echo $user->get('name') ;
echo $user->get('usertype') ;
?>
```

Everything but usertype works, for some reason. Usertype is vital to be able to monetize my app. I followed this as a reference, so it seems alright:

http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_current_user_object

Whats wrong here?

Comment: Flash app? Therefore it's external to the actual Joomla site, so have you imported the Joomla library?

Comment: Well, I call it a flash app, but its basically a Flash swf that checks if the user is logged in and which type he is. Anyway, that code in on the HTML template, to which every echo (on the actual page) works except for the usertype.

Comment: What your trying won't work as `JUser::$usertype` was removed in Joomla 3.0

Comment: Is there an alternative then? Someway that I can diferentiate user from each other? Flash is going to use some "demo" features for "Registered" users, and Full Version for "Paying" users (names can change though).

Comment: I'm searching around for the easiest solution, preferably not a database query which I hope doesn't have to be used. I suggest you look around and test some examples yourself as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, I've had a look around and I can't actually find a decent solution that simply provides you with the name of the group that the user belongs to. Everything else gives you an array or the ID, so I have written a simple function that will get you exactly what you want:

```
function getUserGroup($userId){     
     $db = JFactory::getDbo();

     $query  = $db->getQuery(true);
     $query->select('title')
     ->from('#__user_usergroup_map AS map')
     ->where('map.user_id = '.(int) $userId)
     ->leftJoin('#__usergroups AS a ON a.id = map.group_id');

     $db->setQuery($query);
     $result = $db->loadResult();

     return $result;
}

echo getUserGroup($user->id);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I didn't manage to get this to work, though I fear my execution was poorly made, so I will give it a few more tries. I'm fairly new to coding, so I believe I'm doing some mistake here. Will update in some time.

Comment: Ok no worries. Just to let you know the code does work as I tested it after writing it :)

Comment: As I suspected, I had some other problems in my HTML that prevented that to work correctly. After some cleaning up, I can attest that it does indeed work perfectly. Thanks, Lodder!